# Elixir + Phoenix: delete_resp_cookie does not do anything

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `/logout` endpoint that. I want to delete my `x-auth-token` cookie in that controller action but it isn't doing anything when I check the front end (a react / remix app)

I read the docs and am providing the same options to `delete_resp_cookie` as I did for `put_resp_cookie`: https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#delete_resp_cookie/3

```
  def login_callback(conn, %{"code" => code}) do
    ...

    one_week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60

    conn
    |> put_resp_cookie("x-auth-token", %{job_seeker_id: generated_user.id},
      path: "/",
      max_age: one_week,
      http_only: true,
      secure: true,
      same_site: "strict",
      domain: Application.get_env(:myapp, :client_domain),
      sign: true
    )
    |> redirect(external: "#{Application.get_env(:myapp, :client_url)}/login_success")
  end

  def logout(conn, _params) do
    one_week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60

    conn
    |> delete_resp_cookie("x-auth-token",
      path: "/",
      max_age: one_week,
      http_only: true,
      secure: true,
      same_site: "strict",
      domain: Application.get_env(:myapp, :client_domain),
      sign: true
    )
    |> json(%{success: true})
  end
```

However, after I make the request and check my frontend, the cookie is still there. Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Plug.Conn.delete_resp_cookie` sends a header updating the cookie's max_age and the browser is responsible for actually expiring that data.

Setting the max_age of a cookie to 0 is a common way to delete a cookie. When the browser receives a cookie with max_age=0, it will *typically* delete the cookie immediately. This is setting the cookie's expiration date to a past date (1970), instructing the browser to discard it.

Additionally you should make sure that your frontend javascript is not memoizing or caching the original cookie in some way. (I notice you trigger a redirect on login but not for logout, which may also be playing some role.)